# Converting the Coordinate Reference System (CRS) to Create a Spatial Dataframe using SpatialPoints() in the SP Package

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, spatial, r-sp

**Issue:**

I have a **shapefile** that I've imported into R and I selected the variables of interest for the analysis that I'm conducting. My ultimate aim is to **interpolate the point data** (dolphin IDs) to obtain **sea surface temperature (SST)** values from each individual raster file within a stack of **70+ rasters** from an object called ncin_SST. This object was created using the function stack::raster() from multiple **Aqua Modis netCDF files** contained in one folder and I downloaded the data from the **'Ocean Color Project' from NASA**. My goal is to extract the average SST per ID over the time period across all 70+ raster files from 2016-to 2021.

```
##Stack all the netCDF files and select the variable "sst" from the raster layers
ncin_SST <- raster::stack(filenames, varname = "sst")
```

I imported my shapefile using the function shapefile() in the **rgdal package** and I want to extract **three variables** of interest involving **variable 1 = ID, variable 2 = LONGITUDE, and variable 3 = LATITUDE**. Before I can **interpolate the IDs** with the **object ncin_SST**, I need to produce a spatial data frame from coordinates using the **SpatialPoints()** function from the **sp package**.

When I am attempting to transform the CRS to WG85/UTM 34N, I am getting this error message below.

If anyone is able to help, then many thanks.

**R-code**

#Read our shapefile using the function shapefile() from the raster package

```
Points_shp <- shapefile(".", point_ID.shp")
```

**Check variable headers**

```
head(Points_shp)
```

**Select the variables of interest**

```
coords = cbind(Points_shp$ID, Points_shp$LATITUDE, Points_shp$LONGITUDE)

#Making a spatial data frame from coordinates
#The IDs were documented in WG84/UTM 34N
#Extract the project code for the CRS


CRS("+init=epsg:32634")
```

**Results**

```
Coordinate Reference System:
Deprecated Proj.4 representation:
 +proj=utm +zone=34 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
WKT2 2019 representation:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 34N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 34N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",21,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]],
        ID["EPSG",16034]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["Between 18°E and 24°E, northern hemisphere between equator and 84°N, onshore and offshore. Albania. Belarus. Bosnia and Herzegovina. Bulgaria. Central African Republic. Chad. Croatia. Democratic Republic of the Congo (Zaire). Estonia. Finland. Greece. Hungary. Italy. Kosovo. Latvia. Libya. Lithuania. Montenegro. North Macedonia. Norway, including Svalbard and Bjornoys. Poland. Romania. Russian Federation. Serbia. Slovakia. Sudan. Sweden. Ukraine."],
        BBOX[0,18,84,24]]]
```

**Finalising the spatial coordinate reference data frame**

```
points_spdf = SpatialPoints(coords, proj4string = crs("+proj=utm + zone=34 + datum=WGS84 + units=m + no_defs"))
```

**Error Message**

```
Error in .local(obj, ...) : 
  cannot derive coordinates from non-numeric matrix
```

Comment: can you share `point_ID.shp`?

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm not allowed to share the data contained on the shapefile based on ownership.

Comment: pity.. I suggest moving to the `sf`-package... In my opinion it just work more 'tidy' than `sp`, and integrates nicely with the tidyverse. In the end, you can convert back to sp ojects, with code like `as(mysf, "Spatial")`.

Comment: Many thanks. I will try your suggestion and get back to you.

Comment: One other option is that if you have a shapefile, you can simply read in the spatial data using `readOGR()` if you want to create an `sp::` object or using `read_st()` to create an `sf::` object.  That way you don't have to go through the hassle of redefining the spatial data from the attributes.  That said, your solution below certainly would work.

Comment: Thank you, Sean for your advice, it was deeply appreciated. I am completely new to the analysis of spatial files and it took me a long time to figure out the method below. I tried readOGR() and I kept on getting error messages. I think I will try sf:: objects for the next part of the analysis. I am sorry for asking, would you be able to advise for this question about the CRS with raster files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71781698/converting-the-coordinate-reference-system-crs-of-a-stack-of-70-raster-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#Read our shapefile using the function shapefile() from the raster package

```
Points_shp <- shapefile(".", point_ID.shp")
```

**Check variable headers**

```
head(Points_shp)
```

**Select the variables of interest from the shapefile**

```
#Check the number of layers in Point_shp
dim(Points_shp)
#[1] 635  19

#Check the variable names in the Point_shp object
names(Points_shp)

#making a spatial data frame from coordinates
#EPSG = 32634
CRS("+init=epsg:32634")
coords = cbind(Points_shp$ID, Points_shp$LATITUDE, Points_shp$LONGITUDE)

#Check the variables in the coords object
print(coords)

#check header
head(coords)

#Check the structure of the matrix coords
str(coords)

#Change the matrix coords into a dataframe
coords_N<-as.data.frame(coords)

#Rename Column Names of coords_N dataframe
#Cbind transformed the column headings to V1, V2, and V3
#Change the column names
colnames(coords_N)[colnames(coords_N) == "V1"] <- "ID"
colnames(coords_N)[colnames(coords_N) == "V2"] <- "Longitude"
colnames(coords_N)[colnames(coords_N) == "V3"] <- "Latitude"

#Check the structure of the data frame coords
str(coords_N)

#Change the format of the variables from characters to numerica format
coords_N$ID <- as.numeric(as.character(coords_N$ID))
coords_N$Longitude <- as.numeric(as.character(coords_N$Longitude))
coords_N$Latitude <- as.numeric(as.character(coords_N$Latitude))

#Change latitude and longitude into coordinates using the sp package
coordinates(coords_N) <- ~Latitude + Longitude

#Finalise the coordinate reference system dataframe
points_spdf = SpatialPoints(coords_N, proj4string = crs("+proj=utm + zone=34 + datum=WGS84"))
```