# Converting the Coordinate Reference System (CRS) of a Stack of 70+ Raster Files in stack::raster () Format

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, raster, spatial

**Issue**

I have a batch of **70+ raster files** with the object name **'ncin_SST'** that I created using the function **stack::raster()** in the **raster package**. I want to change the **coordinate reference system (CRS) WG84/34N**.

My ultimate aim is to interpolate the point data (dolphin IDs) in a shapefile to obtain the **sea surface temperature (SST)** values from each individual raster file within the stack of 70+ rasters.

The source of the raster files are **multiple Aqua Modis netCDF files** contained in one folder in my documents and I downloaded the data from the **'Ocean Color Project' from NASA**. My goal is to extract the average SST per ID over the time period across all 70+ raster files from 2016-to 2021.

Firstly, I need to ensure that the **shapefile** and raster files have the same CRS and I have tried various different methods to achieve this output; however, unsuccessfully.

Unfortunately, I cannot share my data online due to ownership of the data.

Many thanks in advance if anyone can help with this error message.

**R-code:**

```
##Open all 70+ Aqua Modis netCDF files from their folder

filenames = list.files('~/Ocean_ColorSST_2016_2021', pattern='*.nc',full.names=TRUE)
```

##Stack all the netCDF files and extract the variable "sst"

```
ncin_SST <- raster::stack(filenames, varname = "sst")
```

**Print Results**

```
print(ncin_SST)

class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 4320, 8640, 37324800, 59  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.04166667, 0.04166667  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90.00001, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
names      : Sea.Surface.Temperature.1, Sea.Surface.Temperature.2, Sea.Surface.Temperature.3, Sea.Surface.Temperature.4, Sea.Surface.Temperature.5, Sea.Surface.Temperature.6, Sea.Surface.Temperature.7, Sea.Surface.Temperature.8, Sea.Surface.Temperature.9, Sea.Surface.Temperature.10, Sea.Surface.Temperature.11, Sea.Surface.Temperature.12, Sea.Surface.Temperature.13, Sea.Surface.Temperature.14, Sea.Surface.Temperature.15, ...
```

**Here's a printout of one single AQUA MODIS FILE:**

```
File AQUA_MODIS.20160901_20160930.L3m.MO.SST.sst.4km.nc (NC_FORMAT_NETCDF4):

     3 variables (excluding dimension variables):
        short sst[lon,lat]   (Chunking: [87,44])  (Compression: shuffle,level 4)
            long_name: Sea Surface Temperature
            scale_factor: 0.00499999988824129
            add_offset: 0
            units: degree_C
            standard_name: sea_surface_temperature
            _FillValue: -32767
            valid_min: -1000
            valid_max: 10000
            display_scale: linear
            display_min: -2
            display_max: 45
        unsigned byte qual_sst[lon,lat]   (Chunking: [87,44])  (Compression: shuffle,level 4)
            long_name: Quality Levels, Sea Surface Temperature
            _FillValue: 255
            valid_min: 0
            valid_max: 5
        unsigned byte palette[eightbitcolor,rgb]   (Contiguous storage)  

     4 dimensions:
        lat  Size:4320
            long_name: Latitude
            units: degrees_north
            standard_name: latitude
            _FillValue: -999
            valid_min: -90
            valid_max: 90
        lon  Size:8640
            long_name: Longitude
            units: degrees_east
            standard_name: longitude
            _FillValue: -999
            valid_min: -180
            valid_max: 180
        rgb  Size:3 (no dimvar)
        eightbitcolor  Size:256 (no dimvar)
[1] ">>>> WARNING <<<  attribute data_bins is an 8-byte value, but R"
[1] "does not support this data type. I am returning a double precision"
[1] "floating point, but you must be aware that this could lose precision!"

    61 global attributes:
        product_name: AQUA_MODIS.20160901_20160930.L3m.MO.SST.sst.4km.nc
        instrument: MODIS
        title: MODISA Level-3 Standard Mapped Image
        project: Ocean Biology Processing Group (NASA/GSFC/OBPG)
        platform: Aqua
        temporal_range: month
        processing_version: R2019.0
        date_created: 2019-12-17T18:25:34.000Z
        history: l3mapgen par=AQUA_MODIS.20160901_20160930.L3m.MO.SST.sst.4km.nc.param
        l2_flag_names: LAND,HISOLZEN
        time_coverage_start: 2016-09-01T00:00:00.000Z
        time_coverage_end: 2016-10-01T02:59:59.000Z
        start_orbit_number: 76217
        end_orbit_number: 76655
        map_projection: Equidistant Cylindrical
        latitude_units: degrees_north
        longitude_units: degrees_east
        northernmost_latitude: 90
        southernmost_latitude: -90
        westernmost_longitude: -180
        easternmost_longitude: 180
        geospatial_lat_max: 90
        geospatial_lat_min: -90
        geospatial_lon_max: 180
        geospatial_lon_min: -180
        latitude_step: 0.0416666679084301
        longitude_step: 0.0416666679084301
        sw_point_latitude: -89.9791641235352
        sw_point_longitude: -179.97917175293
        spatialResolution: 4.64 km
        geospatial_lon_resolution: 0.0416666679084301
        geospatial_lat_resolution: 0.0416666679084301
        geospatial_lat_units: degrees_north
        geospatial_lon_units: degrees_east
        number_of_lines: 4320
        number_of_columns: 8640
        measure: Mean
        suggested_image_scaling_minimum: -2
        suggested_image_scaling_maximum: 45
        suggested_image_scaling_type: LINEAR
        suggested_image_scaling_applied: No
        _lastModified: 2019-12-17T18:25:34.000Z
        Conventions: CF-1.6 ACDD-1.3
        institution: NASA Goddard Space Flight Center, Ocean Ecology Laboratory, Ocean Biology Processing Group
        standard_name_vocabulary: CF Standard Name Table v36
        naming_authority: gov.nasa.gsfc.sci.oceandata
        id: AQUA_MODIS.20160901_20160930.L3b.MO.SST.nc/L3/AQUA_MODIS.20160901_20160930.L3b.MO.SST.nc
        license: https://science.nasa.gov/earth-science/earth-science-data/data-information-policy/
        creator_name: NASA/GSFC/OBPG
        publisher_name: NASA/GSFC/OBPG
        creator_email: data@oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov
        publisher_email: data@oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov
        creator_url: https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov
        publisher_url: https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov
        processing_level: L3 Mapped
        cdm_data_type: grid
        keywords: Earth Science > Oceans > Ocean Optics > Sea Surface Temperature
        keywords_vocabulary: NASA Global Change Master Directory (GCMD) Science Keywords
        data_bins: 20740391
        data_minimum: -1.80000019073486
        data_maximum: 39.9599990844727
```

**Change the CRS to WG84/UTM 34**

```
ncin_SST_34 <- projectRaster(ncin_SST, crs = "+proj=utm + zone=34 + datum=WGS84")
```

**Error Message**

```
Error in rgdal::checkCRSArgs_ng(uprojargs = uprojargs, SRS_string = SRS_string,  : 
  length(SRS_string) == 1L is not TRUE
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (is.na(x)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (x == "") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (substr(x, 1, 1) == "+") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: I used your code on example data from the raster package, and it worked. That suggests to me that the input data is the issue. Can you share at least a portion of the data you are using? Are you able to project one raster from your stack? If so, you could project then stack.

Comment: Hey Skaqqs. I just added a printout of one single Aqua Modis file into this question, and I managed to change the CRS with one single shapefile https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71763547/converting-the-coordinate-reference-system-crs-to-create-a-spatial-dataframe-u?noredirect=1#comment126858271_71763547. I just don't know how to change the CRS for all the Aqua Modis files in the raster::stack() object. I think the issue is that longitude and latitude have not been extracted because I specified SST values

Comment: I've been trying to extract, longitude, latitude, and SST for all 70+ netCDF Aqua Modis files and then input these extracted files into a raster::stack() object to change the CRS. I am so confused and I am also a novice with spatial data. I cannot figure out how to extract the variables of interest beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open a ncdf file with raster data you can simply do

```
library(terra)
x <- rast("filename.nc")
```

if there are multiple variables per file you can select one like this

```
x <- rast("filename.nc", "SST")
```

(or open all of them as a SpatRasterDataset with `sds("filename.nc")`

If you have a vector `ff` that contains multiple filenames of ncdf files for the same area (same extent and resolution) you can do

```
x <- rast(ff, "SST")
```

While it is possible to transform your data to another coordinate reference system such as UTM like this

```
p <- project(x, "+proj=utm + zone=34 + datum=WGS84")
```

That is in most cases not a good idea. First, you should really provide a template raster to project to (see `?project`), but more importantly, projecting raster data distorts the values. So you should avoid that if possible in data analysis (it is ok to make a map in most cases). Instead project the spatial vector data to the CRS of the raster data.

Comment: Thank you, I have taken everything you have said on board and I will use a lat/long project in WG84. I have really appreciated your help